# Possible to test for null records in SQL only?

Tags: sql-server, null

I am trying to help a co-worker with a peculiar problem, and she's limited to MS SQL QUERY code only.  The object is to insert a dummy record (into a surrounding union) IF no records are returned from a query.

I am having a hard time going back and forth from PL/SQL to MS SQL, and I am appealing for help (I'm not particularly appealing, but I am appealing to the StackOverflow audiance).

Basically, we need a single, testable value from the target Select ... statement.

In theory, it would do this:

```
(other records from unions)
Union
   Select "These" as fld1, "are" as fld2, "Dummy" as fld3, "Fields" as fld4 
   where NOT (Matching Logic)
Union
   Select fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4  // Regular records exist
   From tested_table
   Where (Matching Logic)
```

Forcing an individual dummy record, with no conditions, works.

IS there a way to get a single, testable result from a Select?

Can't do it in code (not allowed), but can feed SQL

Anybody?  Anybody?  Bbeller?

Comment: Do you mean: If Not Exist (Matching Logic) return dummy else retun actual

Comment: Yes, that what I meant... my excuse is:  It was late (10+ hrs), I was tired, I was possibly delerious, My glove was too tight, the sun was in my eyes, and I tripped over a log.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `unions` in a `with`, then include another union that returns a `null` only when the big union is empty:

```
; with BigUnion as
         (
         select  *
         from    table1
         union all
         select  *
         from    table2
         )
select   *
from     BigUnion
union all
select   null
where    not exists (select * from BigUnion)
```

Comment: Woohoo!  

We'll try this tomorrow AM (it's late here).  I really appreciate it, and I know my co-worker will also.

If anyone is interested, this is to solve the Graphing Phantom Data problem in Crystal Reports... where the user can specify a command as a data source.

Thank you,

Comment: Thank you, that worked well.  Using the With (which I evidently knew nothing about in that context).  This has increased the report generation speed nicely, obviating the need for repeated calls to the DB server to check for "no records".  And a good reminder to me to use EXISTS more effectively.  Cheers!